# Lua Mouse Drag Quaternion

Tags: lua, rotation, quaternions, fivem

I am looking for a bit of help with this lua script I am making. I want to use Quaternion's to rotate an object based on your mouse movement/drag. I am using this library for my Quaternion https://github.com/topameng/CsToLua/ . I have got the object to move but all the rotations are messed up, here is a link to a video of what I have so far http://img.bcdojrp.net/videos/uploads/2021-03-17%2003-58-07_Trim.mp4 I have spent hours looking this over and can't find what to change... any help is appreciated, thanks!

```lua
function GetCursor()
    local sx, sy = GetActiveScreenResolution()
    local cx, cy = GetNuiCursorPosition()
    local cx, cy = (cx / sx) + 0.008, (cy / sy) + 0.027
    return cx, cy
end
```

```lua
if dragging then
    -- this is the screen position 
    local intx, inty = GetCursor()
    local deltaMove = {
        ['x'] = intx-previousMousePosition.x,
        ['y'] = inty-previousMousePosition.y
    }
    local deltaRotationQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(deltaMove.y * 40, deltaMove.x * 40, 0)
    local x,y,z,w = GetEntityQuaternion(curObject)
    local quatNew = deltaRotationQuaternion.__mul(Quaternion.New(x,y,z,w), deltaRotationQuaternion)
    local valX, valY, valZ, valW = quatNew.x, quatNew.y, quatNew.z, quatNew.w
    SetEntityQuaternion(curObject, valX, valY, valZ, valW)

    --cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
    previousMousePosition.x = intx
    previousMousePosition.y = inty
else
    previousMousePosition = {
        ['x'] = 0,
        ['y'] = 0
    }
end
```

Comment: What are the values `+0.008`,  `+0.027`  and  `*40` doing, are they intended to correct for aspect-ratio?